# PHP error with user agent

Tags: php

```
 <?php
   $os = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   echo $os();
 ?>
```

This code does not work at all, but `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` does work.

EDIT: Please ignore this, I fixed it with `print_r()`;

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php
 $os = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 echo $os;
 ?>
```

$os is a variable not a function